# I need a script to copy <img> tag when switch button is on and to delete <img> tag when switch button is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a script to copy `<img>` tag when switch button is on and to delete  tag when switch button is off. I need a simple way.
Here is button for switch:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
<script language="javascript">
        var changeImage = function(){
            img1="image/rez.jpg";
            switch(document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').src){
                case img1:
                    document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").src=img1;
                break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById("chango").src=img1;
                break;
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Sure, we love to help you with your script. But we won't make it for you from scratch. What have you tried so far?

Comment: do you want to show and hide image when check/uncheck checkbox??

Comment: By the way, where is the `<img>` tag? do you really need to *copy & remove* or just *hide/show* it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to show/hide image, you can use a simple CSS like below.

**CSS**

```
#myonoffswitch ~ img
{
 display:none;
}
#myonoffswitch:checked ~ img
{
 display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="onoffswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
     <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
   <img src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" />
 </div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/xs5yvvvt/)

Comment: and if i want to have buttons in buttons.html and iamges in images.html how i can connect?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pruhv061/)**

HTML:

```
 <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input id="Switch" type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch"/>
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
         <img id="Sample" src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" />

        <div id="Div"></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 var variable;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
            $("#Div").text("");
            if ($('#Switch').is(':checked')) {
                variable = $("#Sample")[0].outerHTML;
                $("#Div").text(variable);
            } else {
                variable = "";
                $("#Div").text(variable);
            }

        });
```

Comment: and if i want to have buttons in buttons.html and iamges in images.html how i can connect?

Answer (score 0):

You just change the source of the image, that will help you..

```
    if(im.src.match(""))
    {
    im.src="D:/Users/tobeused.jpg";
    }

    else
    {
    im.src="";
    }
```